# How to set up DNS and resolv.conf file

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, netplan, resolv.conf

I've had Ubuntu Server 18.04 up and running for a couple weeks. For a while my network interface never connected. I eventually got a proper netplan YAML file setup. I can now ping my servers IP, not hostname, from another computer on my network and also ping outside IPs, not domain names. As stated I am not able to use any domain names. So, things like `ping google.com` and `sudo apt update` fail. I believe it's a DNS issue but am not 100% sure.

Result of `ping google.com`:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Result of `sudo apt update`:

```
 Err3: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
     Temporary failure in resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

There are a few more errors when updating but they all fail to resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'.

My netplan file is `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.40/22]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.0.0, 1.1.1.1]
```

I've seen a lot of post and articles talk about `/etc/resolv.conf`, however mine has always been non-exist. If I would try to `cat` out the contents I would get an error `no such file or directory`. I think this is where my problem is but I also do not understand enough about linux networking to realize what's wrong.

Some people were able to fix this issue by creating or fixing their symbolic links to `/etc/resolv.conf`. However, they used `run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, and other files. Those files/services don't exist on my machine. I only have one networking-related file under `/run` located at `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s25.network`. It's contents are:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s25

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.198.1.40/22
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=8.8.4.4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=1.1.0.0
DNS=1.1.1.1
```

I created a symbolic link from the `/etc/resolv.conf` to the `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s25.network`. The contents of my `resolv.conf` are exactly the same as `10-netplan-enp0s25.network`.

I am confused by what else needs to be done to configure my machine. Everything I have found so far has been very conflicting and hasn't helped.

---

Comment: Do you have `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`? In your .yaml, why /22 instead of /24? re: "I created a symbolic link from the /etc/resolv.conf to the /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s25.network" this is wrong.

Comment: @heynnema I do not. I don't even have a `/run/systemd/resolve` directory. I just saw another config file use /22. I think /24 is what I want though. And I realize my symbolic link was probably wrong but I didn't have anything else to try linking to.

Comment: Although it's not the correct thing to do... manually create/edit a /etc/resolv.conf file and add `nameserver 127.0.0.53`. root ownership. 777 file. Then see if you can resolve FQDN.

Comment: @heynnema won't the file be written though? Possible even before a restart?

Comment: Since it won't be a symlink, it'll be a static file. Not the final way to run, but just for testing. No restart required.

Comment: @heynnema I now have a `resolv.conf` file that reads `nameserver 127.0.0.53`. I ran `sudo chmod 777 resolv.conf` and then `ping google.com`. I still get `Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: I suspected that wouldn't work. `sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf`. Before I recommend that you reinstall Ubuntu, lets check one last thing. `dpkg -l *resolv*`.

Comment: @heynnema I ran `sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` and then `dpkg -l *resolv*`. I got name = resolvconf, Version = <None>, Achitecture=<None>, Desciption="no description available"

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`, reboot, then review the three locations in /run to see if the *resolv.conf file exists, and if so, what its contents are. If one exists, we'll symlink it to /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: @heynnema I can't install any packages or use update. I get `Temporary failure in resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'` for both. Can I download resolvconf from another machine and install it from a usb?

Comment: Go to packages.ubuntu.com and download the appropriate resolvconf for your OS. Put it on a flash key, and do it that way. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/resolvconf there are a number of dependencies that you **may** have to download. If that's too much of a hassle, just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema I was able to install resolvconf. If run `dpkg -l resolvconf` I get name=resolvconf, version=1.79ubuntu10, architecture=all, description="name server information handler". I tried pining again but it failed, same error. I restarted my machine just in case but no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Go ahead and just reinstall Ubuntu. If it asks to replace any modified files, say yes. Report back.

Comment: What does `systemctl status systemd-resolved` report on the affected system?

Comment: You should really not install resolvconf on an Ubuntu 18.04 system using netplan, even for debugging.

Comment: @slangasek @heynnema I will be away from my server for most of today. I'll report back later with the `systemctl status systemd-resolved` and then possibly a re-install

Comment: @slangasek so after running `systemctl status systemd-resolved` I get Loaded: "loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled ; vendor preset; enabled)", Active: "inactive (dead)", and Docs: "links to freedesktop.org docs"

Comment: Ok, so this service should not be disabled.  Do you know how it came to be disabled?  (And you should re-enable it to fix your problem, by running 'sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.status'.)

Comment: @slangasek I do not know how it came to be disabled. I ran `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved` since sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.status didn't exist. It created two symlinks. Both point to `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service`. However, running `ping google.com` still fails and when running `systemctl status systemd-resolved` the service is still listed as "inactive (dead)"

Comment: Does this change if you also run `systemctl start systemd-resolved`?

Comment: @slangasek That did it! Thank you guys! The service is listed as active now and `ping` works

Comment: Great, thanks for following up.  I've attempted to condense the content thread into an answer for benefit of future inquirers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an Ubuntu 18.04 system, `/etc/resolv.conf` should always be a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, unless the `resolvconf` package is installed (not recommended for new systems), in which case it should be a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.  If `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` does not exist, check that the `systemd-resolved` service is running (`systemctl status systemd-resolved`).  If it is not active, enable and start it (`sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved && sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved`) which should correct the problem.

Comment: I would note that you might also need to install resolvconf. Or at least I did, I'm not sure if it was absolutely needed or not?

Comment: It was not needed. resolvconf is only needed when you are upgrading and have certain types of network configurations set up using `ifupdown`.